# Numpy Array composed of arrays full of dictionaries, selection issue

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code :

```
example = {'ABC':16, 'DEF':17, 'GHI':18, 'JKL':19, 'MNO':20},{'ABC':16, 'DEF':17, 'GHI':18, 'JKL':19, 'MNO':20},{'ABC':16, 'DEF':17, 'GHI':18, 'JKL':19, 'MNO':20}, {'ABC':16, 'DEF':17, 'GHI':18, 'JKL':19, 'MNO':20},
example = np.array(example)
print(example)
```

Multiplied several times so that I have an array composed of arrays like this one. I am trying to let's say retrieve all the 'ABC' values in one array. When I try

```
example[0]['ABC']
```

I get 16 as it should, but if I try

```
example[:]['ABC']
```

I get an error

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

(In my real array I do `example[0][0]['ABC']` to retrieve one specific index because there is one more dimension but I believe the solution is the same, but just in case I put this precision.

Thanks all

Comment: A typo: `example[:]['ABC]` is  missing a `'` after `ABC`

Comment: The existing answers correctly point out why that line gives you an error. What would you liked to have as a result?

Comment: You have created an object dtype array, which is more like a list than a regular numeric array.  It doesn't have any special handling for dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trying to interpret `'ABC'` as an index of the array. `numpy` does not support doing this with dictionaries (as far as I know) without using something like structured arrays. Instead, you could create a `list` of all the 'ABC' values corresponding to each `dict`:

```
example = {'ABC':16, 'DEF':17, 'GHI':18, 'JKL':19, 'MNO':20},{'ABC':16, 'DEF':17, 'GHI':18, 'JKL':19, 'MNO':20},{'ABC':16, 'DEF':17, 'GHI':18, 'JKL':19, 'MNO':20}, {'ABC':16, 'DEF':17, 'GHI':18, 'JKL':19, 'MNO':20}
example = np.array(example)
values = [d['ABC'] for d in example]
print(values) # [16, 16, 16, 16]
```

Or for your 2D use case:

```
example = np.array([example, example])
values = [d['ABC'] for sub in example for d in sub]
print(values) # [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16]
```

Comment: I see ! Thanks a lot ! It's more complex than I hoped especially when I will try to find specific indexes and loops through them (like each max, each first etc...) do you happen to know what part of the numpy doc covers that ? Cheers !

Comment: No problem, and what do you mean by each max and each first? There are functions like [`np.max`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax) which allow you to find the max of an array

Comment: yeah I meant stuff like np.max, but inside a loop it's more tricky, like would  `values = [np.max(d['ABC']) for sub in example for d in sub]` work ? I don't think so, I don't really know how to use loops with arrays, that's why I was wondering ig you had links to docs or tutorials.

Comment: @JamesChen ah ok, unfortunately I'm not sure about any docs or anything but you may want to look into using Python's `max` where you can specify a function as a `key` parameter to select the correct key-value pair from the dictionary: `max(example, key=lambda i: i['ABC'])`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `example[:]` is the same as `example`. Hence when you are trying to find index `ABC`, it will error because you are evaluating on the original array.